# Ignore escape sequences in strings java?

Tags: c#, java

In C#, I can write the string `"\\myDir\\myFile"` as `@"\myDir\myFile"`. What is the equivalent for this "@" character in Java, if any?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To my knowledge no such equivalence exist in the Java language definition.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to Use Unix-style paths in Java. Java will find out what the real paths are in all File-based code.

```
System.out.println(new File("c:/dev/m2-repo/org/apache/ant").getCanonicalPath());
```

Output:

> C:\dev\m2-repo\org\apache\ant

BTW if it's the root drive, you can skip the drive letter. Java will understand `/programs` if you look for `C:\programs`

Answer (score 1):

There is no equivalent in Java.

For this concrete case you can use `File.separator + "myDir" + File.separator + "myFile"`

Comment: Although you'd be better off using the `new File(...)` constructors, IMO.